# What is the difference between empty project with /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS and empty window desktop project?

Tags: project, visual-studio-2022, subsystem

In Visual Studio 2022, I thought changing /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE to /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOW from "empty project" and "Window Desktop project with empty toggle on" produces exactly same result, or executable, so far because all project settings were identical and winmain entry point worked properly with #include <windows.h>.

However, I recently found out that executable compiled from "empty project" set to /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOW executable does not work with "Open with" while "Window Desktop project with empty toggle on" works.

Message box pops up and says "Cannot associate a file type with a program. The program you have selected cannot be associated with this file type. Please choose another program."

This means there IS a difference between them which is neither code nor project setting. Does anyone can explain what differences exist between the two?

Comment: What do you mean by `executable does not work with "Open with"`? What did you try to do and cannot do it?

Comment: I've tried to "Open with" my executable produced from each case, ultimately to set portable app as default app. However, executable produced from empty project setting /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOW pops the message box and unable to perform "Open with" operation while Window Desktop project with empty toggle on does not pop the message box and "Open with" is successful.

Comment: Firstly I thought there will be some difference in project setting. And after checking, I found that project setting is identical. Then I reached "then why?"